# Unable to install OpenJDK 9 on 32-bit Lubuntu or 64-bit Ubuntu machines

Tags: openjdk

I'm brushing up on Java, working from the Deitel book Java 9 For Programmers. The first 15 chapters required Java SE 8, and I remember the installation process being an easy command-line job - `sudo apt-get install ...` etc.

At the end of Chapter 16 comes the first example requiring Java 9, which has brought my progress to a halt. I have spent nearly 2 hours this evening trying to find a way to install OpenJDK 9. The error is:

```
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-9-jdk
```

The biggest difficulty seems to be finding any results for this exact error. There are numerous posts on altogether different kinds of OpenJDK 9 install problems, although most search results are for OpenJDK 8. Several posts advise using the command I used - `sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jdk`. I've made sure the universe, multiverse repositories are on, `sudo apt-get update` etc., but no joy.

Can one install JDK 9 on Ubuntu?

Comment: JDK 9  is not supported anymore. Please use JDK10 instead. It should be backwards compatible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Answer (score 5):

JDK 9 is not supported anymore. You should use JDK 10 (or any newer version available) More details on the Wikipedia page of the [Java Version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history).

To do this, install the [default-jdk](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/default-jdk) package.